# Is there a diffrence between saying "盗み聞き" and "盗み聞きとは?"

Tags: words, nuances

I know that "盗み聞き" would be "Eavesdrop" or "Eavesdropping," but I wasn't sure if the addition of "とは" modified the word in some way or if it perhaps just indicated something about the wording.

Edit: For context, the exact line of text is
"盗み聞きとは・・・。太陽の使者ともあろうものが行儀が悪いな？"

Comment: It sounds like you’ve heard or read this in a very specific context, but then posted here without including any of that context.

Comment: My apologies, basically the context is just someone accusing someone else of eavesdropping, the exact line of text is literally "盗み聞きとは..." However, the following line has them state that such an act is unbefitting because of their title/status.

Comment: Can you include some of the text that goes before and after the particular phrase in question?  One or two sentences should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, it's a shortening of something like 盗み聞きとは卑怯な, 盗み聞きとは倫理に悖る, 盗み聞きとは油断も隙もない. What exactly is shortened must be guessed from the context.

It can be used in a very versatile way, e.g. 人助けとは...(殊勝だ), 泣くとは...(情けない), 火事とは...(驚いた).